# User input based equation with Eq()

Tags: python, sympy

So I am new to Sympy and I was looking to try making a calculator that can take it's equation from the user. I tried using Eq() and have it like this:(on Jupyter notebook)

```
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex=True)
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

sp.init_session()

inpb = input("Before '=':\n> ")
inpa = input("After '=':\n> ")

eqn = Eq(inpb, inpa)
display(eqn)
```

As I know very little about this I don't have an idea on how to do this, the code obviously did not work so I would like some help on how to do it. If I have to use a different library please do tell.

Edit: Thank you Furas for the help, using eval() worked. I'll keep in mind putting the traceback error for any future posts.

Comment: do you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback")in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other usful nformation.

Comment: how about `Eq(eval(inpb), eval(inpa))` . As I rember `sympy` should have own function `eval()` os something similar to "evaluate" string.

Comment: `sympify` which uses standard `eval()`- [Converting Strings to SymPy Expressions¶](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#converting-strings-to-sympy-expressions), `parse_expr` - [Parsing](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html)